# Copy a Bash array with empty elements

Tags: arrays, bash, copy

I'm having problems in bash (ver 4.2.25) copying arrays with empty elements.  When I make a copy of an array into another variable, it does not copy any empty elements along with it.

```
#!/bin/bash

array=( 'one' '' 'three' )
copy=( ${array[*]} )

IFS=$'\n'

echo "--- array (${#array[*]}) ---"
echo "${array[*]}"

echo
echo "--- copy (${#copy[*]}) ---"
echo "${copy[*]}"
```

When I do this, here is the output:

```
--- array (3) ---
one

three

--- copy (2) ---
one
three
```

The original array has all three elements including the empty element, but the copy does not.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have a quoting problem and you should be using `@`, not `*`. Use:

```
copy=( "${array[@]}" )
```

From the [`bash(1)` man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/bash/):

> Any  element  of  an  array may be referenced using **`${name[subscript]}`**.
>          The braces are required to avoid conflicts with pathname expansion.  If
>          **`subscript`**  is  **`@`**  or **`*`**, the word expands to all members of **`name`**.  These
>          subscripts differ only when the word appears within double quotes.   If
>          the word is double-quoted, **`${name[*]}`** expands to a single word with the
>          value of each array member separated by the first character of the  **`IFS`**
>          special variable, and **`${name[@]}`** expands each element of **`name`** to a separate word.

Example output after that change:

```
--- array (3) ---
one

three

--- copy (3) ---
one

three
```

Comment: I doubt it - do you have both the `@` and the double quotes?  I just added some example output.

Comment: Oh, the double quotes!  Sorry, didn't see the double quotes.  Yep, that worked.  So help me out, why do the quotes make this work?

Comment: With the double quotes and the `@`, that word expands to `"one" "" "three"`.  Without them, it expands to `one three`.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with [Bash 4.3](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES), you can do this

```
$ alpha=(bravo charlie 'delta  3' '' foxtrot)

$ declare -n golf=alpha

$ echo "${golf[2]}"
delta  3
```